# Terminal periodically swarmed with kbuildsyscoca4 lines

Tags: xfce4-terminal, konqueror

Every several hours, my terminal session is hit with hundreds of lines starting with `kbuildsycoca4(10461)`.

An example line is `kbuildsycoca4(10461) KBuildServiceFactory::populateServiceTypes: "phononbackends/gstreamer.desktop" specifies undefined mimetype/servicetype "video/anim"`

This started happening yesterday when I installed konqueror from the Ubuntu Software Center. However, I've since removed konqueror and the issue persists.

What is causing this and how can I remove the nuisance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1660470), you may be able to disable it with:

> Hmm, any and each of these may be enough. In order of neatness and
>   effort needed;
>
> A. Start kdebugdialog and tick Disable all debug output.
>
> B. Open up that `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`, look for lines including `mplayer.desktop` and redact it or remove the entire
>   section including it.
>
> C. Start your programs with `dolphin &>/dev/null`. Or to fork and disown it; `dolphin &>/dev/null & disown $!`. Annoying workaround
>   though.

With C, `dolphin > /dev/null 2>&1 & disown` may be better though.

The problem is probably caused by the `kbuildsycoca4` executable, which is provided by the [`kdelibs-bin` or `kdelibs5-dbg` packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=i386&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=kbuildsycoca4), which were likely installed as a dependency of konqueror. So you may be able to fix your issue with one of these commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove kdelibs5-dbg
sudo apt-get remove kdelibs-bin
```

Note if you want other KDE apps they may be removed as well.

Comment: Did that. Now I'm getting `/org/freedesktop/UDisks2 ...` spillover. I searched `dpkg --list | grep kde`, and a number of packages show. Is that the best way to find out which dependencies remain?

Comment: @cfye14 - to remove all the kde pacakges it may be best to use a package manager like Synaptic then, as you can easily select all the packages and remove them. What new errors are you getting?

Comment: Continuing to get errors like this: `"/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb" lost interfaces: ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.PartitionTable")` ... they all have that form, more or less